# How to prevent typing in a TextArea also triggering Key Bindings?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, key-bindings

I am trying to implement hotkeys in a JFrame with a split pane that has a JTree on one of the panes. The key bindings work great, except that when a user is editing the name of a JTree node if they press a key that has a key binding the keystroke is typed in the text area **and** it triggers the key binding. Any ideas on how to allow the editing of nodes, while still implementing hotkeys?

Below is an example that demonstrates the behavior. The "1" and "2" keys are bound, so if you type either one in the text area, you'll see the popup.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeyBindingTest {
    static JButton button1;
    static JButton button2;
    static JPanel panel;

    public KeyBindingTest() {
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
        tb.setFloatable(false);

        button1 = new JButton("First Button");
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        button2 = new JButton("Second Button");
        button2.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        tb.add(button1);
        tb.add(button2);

        panel.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        JScrollPane opts = new JScrollPane(ta);
        panel.add(opts, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setKeyBindings(tb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                KeyBindingTest test = new KeyBindingTest();
                test.createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(JToolBar tb) {
        tb.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "first");
        tb.getActionMap().put("first", new ButtonAction());
        tb.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, 0), "second");
        tb.getActionMap().put("second", new ButtonAction());
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button1);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You pressed a button \n" + e.paramString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reason why typically hotkeys have an Alt or Control modifier.

You can modify the Action to determine which component has focus:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    Component focusedComponent = kfm.getFocusOwner();

    if (focusedComponent instanceof JTextArea)
        return;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You pressed a button \n"+e.paramString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can accept that the answer is mostly, "Don't do it the way you're doing it." :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done Swing, but I think you can call consume() on the ActionEvent to prevent it from being passed to other listeners. I.e., if you call consume before the keystroke hits the other listeners, you can prevent the numbers from showing up in the field.

To clarify:

```
public class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You pressed a button \n"+e.paramString());
        e.consume();
    }
}
```

You might have to account for the order of the listeners though (like I said, it's been a while.)

Comment: Thank you! I thought of that, but consume() isn't available on an ActionEvent.

Comment: How's that? ActionEvent inherits from AWTEvent, which is where the consume() method comes from. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html

(Sorry; wrong link. Fixed.)

Comment: If consume isn't available, you could try to add a KeystrokeListener to the node to undo the addition of the numbers 1 or 2 when the user types them.

Comment: It's apparently not visible. I think I saw that it's protected, but I can't remember where I saw that now.

Comment: That's right! Sorry; my head is too far out of the Swing game at the moment. Ugh.

Comment: There's no guarantee that 1- They action will be called before the others and 2- And the dispatcher will check the state of the event, `KeyListener` is notorious for ignoring it